# How to handle numbers with more than 3000 digits?

Tags: java, numbers, digits, largenumber

```
int p=223;
int q=569;
int n=p*q;
double num=65;
double d=100877;
exp=Math.pow(num,d);
c=(exp)%n;
System.out.print(expo);
System.out.print("\n"+Math.pow(65, 100877));
```

OUTPUT:
2147483647
Infinity

but the actual result has more than 3000 digits, how can i get complete number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) should help you to do that calculation. But I am afraid you can use [Math.pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) , as it may not be able to generate the big number as you desire. [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) will be limited by the range of double as the method signature uses double for both input and returning the output. You may have to implement your own pow method which should return a BigInteger.

**Edit:** I just checked it and found that [java.math.BigInteger.pow(int exponent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) will be your friend.

Comment: @Divers `mod`? It is `pow`, `mod` doesn't return the power.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). It will help.